# Why do python 2d lists share their elements one another?

Tags: python, list

When I run **this:**

```py
l = [0] * 5

l[0] = 1
l[1] = 2

print(l)
```

I get `[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]`.

But when I run **this:**

```py
l = [[]] * 5

l[0].append(1)
l[1].append(2)

print(l)
```

then I get `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]`.
I expected *`[[1], [2], [], [], []]`.*

What is difference between `[k]*n` and `[[]]*n`?
And **why do the lists share their elements one another?**

Plus, how can I make 2d list without element-sharing lists more briefly than **this?**

```py
l = []
for i in range(5):
    l.append([])

l[0].append(1)
l[1].append(2)

print(l)
```

*It gives `[[1], [2], [], [], []]`.*

Thank you.

Comment: `l = [[]]` is a list containg a list. So `l[0].append(1)` appends the element 1 to the list inside the list. Therefore `[[1]]`. `l[0].append(2)` apends the element 2 to the list 0 inside list. Thereafter `[[1,2]]`

Comment: `[[]] * 5` gives you five identical references to _the same list_.  If you append to one of them, they all get appended, because _they're the same object_.